# How can I retrieve coordinates on a mouse click with ViewportPointToLocation?

Tags: c#, bing-maps

I'm using Bing map WPF control SDK to try retrieving coordinates and printing them

I've managed to retrieve the coordinates of the center of the current LocationRect using an EventHandler associated with pressing the arrows
I've tried employing the same concept with mouse clicking event handlers but it didn't work, first I've registered the event using the += notation as follows:

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MainMap.Mode = new AerialMode(true);
            MainMap.Focus();
            MainMap.Culture = "ar-sa";

            MainMap.MouseDoubleClick += new MouseButtonEventHandler(MapWithPushpins_MouseDoubleClick);
        }

private void MapWithPushpins_MouseDoubleClick(object sender,  MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;

        Point mousePosition = e.GetPosition(this);
        Location pinLocation = MainMap.ViewportPointToLocation(mousePosition);

        Pushpin pin = new Pushpin();
        pin.Location = pinLocation;


        Coordinates.Text = pinLocation.Longitude.ToString();
        MainMap.Children.Add(pin);

    }
```

And here's the `XAML` file:

```
<Window x:Class="Ornina.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:m="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF;assembly=Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Ornina"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" >
            <m:Map CredentialsProvider="AqCitpgSjIz_Sxd6AyI9Zm1rs1uRSG_G3Y7ebfok69ufB8W8uRdUtvheaRbz_10t" x:Name="MainMap" Center="36,38" ZoomLevel="16" Mode="AerialWithLabels" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="300" Width="500">
            </m:Map>
        </Grid>
        <TextBlock x:Name="Coordinates">Coordinations</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The program isn't responding with any thing, no exceptions, no errors

Comment: Did you put a break point to see if you got to your code?  Did you register the Click Event?

Comment: @jdweng of course I've registered the click event on MainWindow using the += notation

Comment: Is the event handler not invoked? Or is the result not what you expect?

Comment: @HHLV when I double click anywhere on the map nothing happens the coordinates are not printed, how can I make sure that the event is invoked? I've already registered it

Comment: As jdweng suggested, you can put a breakpoint to see if your method is invoked. Set the breakpoint to the first line `e.Handled = true;` and run in Debug.

Comment: @HHLV I've just done what you guys advised me to, no hit counts, when I double click the event is not invoked

Comment: Can you share the code where you registered the event handler to the Click event?

Comment: @HHLV I've just edited the post, kindly take a look

Comment: The main method is only called one.  So it must mean that after the main was called you create a new MainMap so the code isn't recognizing the click event.

Comment: @jdweng so I have to somehow invoke the event inside the event handler?

Comment: It doesn't look like there's a problem in the code you posted, but some other part of the code might interfere by unregistering the event handler or replacing the MainMap object. If there is any other relevant code, please add it to your question.

Comment: @HHLV I've just added the XAML file, do you think there's something wrong with it?

Comment: You may not be clicking the right item in the map.  There are different object in the map control.  I would add an exception handler to see if you are getting an exceptions.  See : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/57232544-18d0-4565-a1e6-8b7051064236/bing-maps-wpf-control-c-click-map-objects-and-getting-session-key-from-bing-maps-key?forum=bingmapsservices

Comment: @jdweng I've tried a try-catch block, no exceptions was raised

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your TextBlock is in front of your map, so the map doesn't receive the MouseDoubleClick event.

You can change the TextBlock to:

```
  <TextBlock x:Name="Coordinates"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             VerticalAlignment="Top"
             Text="Coordinations" />
```

So it's only in the top left corner and not in front of the whole map.

Or you can move it outside of the map entirely, in a different grid row or column.

Comment: Whoever you are, I'm deeply in love with you, thanks a ton